# Combine files based on columns

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have 100 files that I want to merge based on `mir_seq` in the files. The output should be one file that contains `mir_seq` and the column `freq` from the original files.

The files look like this:

file1:

```
 mir_seq                                    seq                      name                   freq    mir start   end mism    add t5  t3  s5  s3  DB  ambiguity
hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT  TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT seq_100006_x0     0 hsa-miR-143-3p  61  81  6AT u-TT    0   0   AGTCTGAG    GCTCAGGA    miRNA   1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA seq_100012_x1   1   hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  43  1GT u-A 0   u-G TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG seq_100013_x54  54  hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  44  1GT 0   0   0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
```

file2:

```
mir_seq                                  seq    name    freq    mir start   end mism    add t5  t3  s5  s3  DB    ambiguity
hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT  TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT seq_100006_x1   1   hsa-miR-143-3p  61  81  6AT u-TT    0   0   AGTCTGAG    GCTCAGGA    miRNA   1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA seq_100012_x0   0   hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  43  1GT u-A 0   u-G TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG seq_100013_x24  24  hsa-miR-10a-5p  22  44  1GT 0   0   0   TATATACC    TGTGTAAG    miRNA   1
hsa-miR-1296-5p_TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT    TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT    seq_100019_x17  17  hsa-miR-1296-5p 16  35  0   0   0   u-CC    TGGGTTAG    CTCCTTTA    miRNA   1
```

The files are named like this and only differ in the part between `_` and `.txt.mirna` and is tab-separated:

```
Miraligner_94G.txt.mirna
Miraligner_944G.txt.mirna
```

The output files should be something like this:

```
mir_seq                                  freq_94G     freq_944G     freq_912R
hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT   0            12            55
```

Comment: I am not understanding the question. Do you want to have a single file with all rows of all files merged into a single file, by filtering the `mir_seq` and `freq` columns? Or do you want to filter `mir_seq` as well by some filter?

Comment: This is quite broad. What about stripping the unnecessary aspects of the question and work on a simple input with a desired, clean output. Also, can you show some of your attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, given you're processing files:

```
Miraligner_94G.txt.mirna
Miraligner_944G.txt.mirna
```

It looks like you're just picking out the columns from each.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my %seen;

foreach my $file ( glob("Miraligner_*") ) {
    my ($freq_id) = ( $file =~ m/\_(\w+).txt/ );
    $freq_id = "freq_$freq_id";
    $seen{$freq_id}++;
    open( my $input, "<", $file ) or die $!;
    my @headers = split( ' ', <$input> );
    while (<$input>) {
        my %line;
        @line{@headers} = split;
        my $key = $line{'mir_seq'};
        $data{$key}{$freq_id} = $line{'freq'};
    }
    close($input);
}

my @cols = sort keys %seen;
print join( "\t", "mir_seq", @cols ), "\n";
foreach my $mir_seq ( sort keys %data ) {
    my @output_cols = map { $_ // 0 } @{ $data{$mir_seq} }{@cols};
    print join( "\t", $mir_seq, @output_cols ), "\n";
}
```

Given your dataset outputs (tab separated):

```
mir_seq freq_944G   freq_94G
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA  1   0
hsa-miR-10a-5p_GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG  54  24
hsa-miR-1296-5p_TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT    0   17
hsa-miR-143-3p_TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT  0   1
```

Note - if a value is undefined, it'll print a zero currently. You'll need to amend that map if you want to print something else.

It also sorts alphabetically on most of these - which also may not be what you want, but there are plenty of examples of sorting that you can refer to.

Comment: I got this error:  Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after } = $line{<-- HERE near column 39 at merge.pl line 17.

Comment: Stray character from copy and paste maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You only provided one sample input file so obviously this is untested since you can't test a "merge" with just 1 file:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {
    split(FILENAME,tmp,/[_.]/)
    sfx = tmp[2]
    sfxs[sfx]
}
{
    keys[$1]
    val[$1,sfx] = $4
}
END {
    printf "mir_seq"
    for (sfx in sfxs) {
        printf "%sfreq_%s", OFS, sfx
    }
    print ""

    for (key in keys) {
        printf "%s", key
        for (sfx in sfxs) {
            printf "%s%d", OFS, val[key,sfx]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' Miraligner_*
```